# wpfでウィンドウロード時などに自動で非同期処理を待つ方法

Tags: c#, wpf, 非同期

ユーザーコントロールのコンストラクタをasyncのメソッドにすることができないので、`OnInitialized`をオーバーライドしてそれをasyncにし、その中で非同期処理をawaitで待ってみましたがデッドロックしました。
コンストラクタで待つと当然のようにデッドロックしました。

```
    public partial class AccountCreator : UserControl
    {
        AccountCreatorViewModel _vm = new AccountCreatorViewModel();

        public AccountCreator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _vm.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
```

`ConfigureAwait(false)`によってUIスレッドに戻さないようにしてもだめなようです。

ユーザーによるボタン操作等ではなく、コントロールやウィンドウの初期化時に非同期処理をデッドロックさせずに待つ方法はありますか？

追記：
この質問に至った背景
アプリケーションを起動した際に、GoogleスプレッドシートAPIを使用してスプレッドシートの内容を読み込みます。 ネットワークの通信を行うため、その処理は非同期にしてあります。 通信にそこまでの時間はかかりませんが、ユーザーがボタン等を操作しなくても通信処理は走っていてほしいため、このような質問をしました。

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370) では無いですか？ 貴方が直面している問題とその背景、そして実際には何を如何したいか、それは何故かといったことを追記すると助言や回答が付きやすいでしょう。例えば最初に書いた「ユーザーコントロールのコンストラクタをasyncのメソッドにする」ことを実現したいと考えたのは何故なのか？何が問題でどういう動作や状態になれば良いのか？といったことが書かれていると、実は別の方法で改善・解決させる可能性もあり得るでしょう。

Comment: アプリケーションを起動した際に、GoogleスプレッドシートAPIを使用してスプレッドシートの内容を読み込みます。
ネットワークの通信を行うため、その処理は非同期にしてあります。
通信にそこまでの時間はかかりませんが、ユーザーがボタン等を操作しなくても通信処理は走っていてほしいため、このような質問をしました。

Comment: コメントで追記するのでは無く質問記事自身を編集してください。

Comment: 追記いたしました。アドバイス有難うございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

呼び出し側で ConfigureAwait(false) を付与しても意味が無いのでは？

ReadAsync() の中はどうなっているのでしょう？　たぶんその中で await を使っているのではないかと思いますが、であれば、そこで ConfigureAwait(false) を使うべきと思います。以下のようにできるのであればそれで試してみたはいかがですか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみに、上の画像の TimeCosumingMethod メソッドのコメントアウトした方のコードではデッドロックになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: ReadAsync以降に呼ばれるTaskを返すメソッド呼び出し全てにConfigureAwait(false)をつけたところ、デッドロックしなくなりました。
一つでもつけ忘れるとだめなようですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。